# Why i get error with Interfaces and Observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, rxjs

I build ToDoApp and connect firebase to my project but i have error.

```
ERROR in src/app/todo-component/todo-component.component.ts(25,7): error TS2740: Type 'DocumentChangeAction<{}>[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<ToDoInterface[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 5 more.
```

Here my ToDOInterface:

```
export interface  ToDoInterface {
  id?: string;
  title?: string;
  completed?: boolean;
}
```

My ToDoService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {ToDoInterface} from './ToDoInterface'
import {AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument} from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ToDoService {
  public toDoArray:ToDoInterface[] = [
    {
      id: "sdfsdf",
      title: 'Todo one',
      completed: false
    },
    {
      id: "13dsfsdf",
      title: 'Todo two',
      completed: false
    },
    {
      id: "safsdf",
      title: 'Todo third',
      completed: false
    }
  ];
  ToDoCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<ToDoInterface>;
  ToDo: Observable<ToDoInterface[]>;
  ToDoCollectionName: string = "ToDo";
  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {

  }
  getToDos(){
    return this.toDoArray;
  }
  getToDosFirebase(){
    return this.firestore.collection(this.ToDoCollectionName).snapshotChanges();
  }
  changeToDos(index,property,value){
    this.toDoArray[index][property] = value;
  }
  deleteToDos(index){
    this.toDoArray.splice(index,1);
  }
  deleteToDosFirebase(index){
    // this.firestore.collection("ToDO").doc(index).delete();
  }
  addToDos(obj: ToDoInterface){
    this.toDoArray.push(obj);
  }
  addToDosFirebase(obj: ToDoInterface){
    return new Promise<any>(((resolve, reject) => {
      this.firestore
        .collection("ToDo")
        .add(obj)
        .then(res => console.log('data send!'), err => reject(err))
    }))
  }
}
```

And my function what i call in ngOnInit

```
getToDo(){
    this._toDoService.getToDosFirebase().subscribe(items => {
      this.toDosFirebase = items;
      console.log(items);
    });
```

Maybe i dont know some about rxjs but here data from that func if `toDosFirebase: Observable<any[]>;` and how i can see it normal for my Interface

[image]

In service i hardcode data and all works fine, and my hardcoded data by types equal data from firebase.

Do like in official documentation:

```
private ToDoCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<ToDoInterface>;
  ToDo: Observable<ToDoIdInterface[]>;
  ToDoCollectionName: string = "ToDo";
  constructor(private readonly firestore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.ToDoCollection = firestore.collection<ToDoInterface>(this.ToDoCollectionName);
    this.ToDo = this.ToDoCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as ToDoInterface; //ERROR
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return {id, ...data}
        }
      ));
    console.log(this.ToDo);
  }
```

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: `getToDo(){
    this._toDoService.getToDosFirebase().subscribe(items => {
      this.toDosFirebase = items; //ERRRRRRRROORR
      console.log(items);
    });
  }`

Answer (score 1):

In your "getToDosFirebase" method you are calling a ".snapshotChanges();" method.

> Actions returned by snapshotChanges are of type DocumentChangeAction
>   and contain a type and a payload. The type is either added, modified
>   or removed and the payload contains the document's id, metadata and
>   data.

In other words you need to map the received data something like this:

```
.snapshotChanges()
.map(actions => {
   return actions.map(a => {

     //Get document data
     const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Task;

     //Get document id
     const id = a.payload.doc.id;

     //Use spread operator to add the id to the document data
     return { id, …data };
   });
});
```

For more information see these links: [link1](https://alligator.io/angular/cloud-firestore-angularfire/), [link2](https://medium.com/@coderonfleek/firebase-firestore-and-angular-todo-list-application-d0fe760f6bca)

**update**

In your "to-do-service.service.ts"

change this line:

```
ToDo: Observable<ToDoIdInterface[]>;
```

to this:

```
ToDo: Observable<any>;
```

also change this:

```
map(a => {
```

to this:

map((a: any) => {

After this the project should build correctly.

Comment: I updated question. Now i have err 
`TS2322: Type 'Observable<{ title: string; completed: boolean; id: any; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<ToDoIdInterface[]>'.   Type '{ title: string; completed: boolean; id: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ToDoIdInterface[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.`

Comment: https://github.com/fpsstyle228/todo-app/blob/master/src/app/to-do-service.service.ts - project on github